# snowflake cost management page limited warehouse access to role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

the requirement is to allow to see only granted warehouse view on Snowflake cost management page, and not whole account level ware houses to specific function roles.

is that really possible, cause if I followed https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/cost-exploring-overall#label-cost-accessing-data this does not solve the purpose, as privileges granted role can see even other warehouses in "account option" and I want to restrict the role to show only specific Warehouse details.

Comment: You could create a secure view over the account usage views that limit warehouses based on the warehouses that a user/role have access to.